# Draw a sprite onto the map not to the screen

Tags: java, camera, sprite, libgdx

I'm using libgdx and I have a tiled map which i want to draw the sprite onto. However the sprite is drawn onto the actual window so when I move the camera, the sprite stays in the same place. ?I want to the sprite to move on the map.

This is how i currently render my objects

```
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        translateCamera();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();

        renderer.setView(camera);

        renderer.render(bgLayers);
        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(splayerSprite, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2,
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

        batch.end();
        renderer.render(fgLayers);

    }
```

It always end up being in the middle of the screen, however I want to be able to move them seperatly like for example the camera with (W,A,S,D) and move my player with the direction keys. Then if I want the camera locks onto the player but other wise its free.

I'm new to libgdx so please bear with me, Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the [SpriteBatch](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) projection matrix isn't being set to the [Camera](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html) projection matrix.  This means the `Sprite` is not being rendered relative to the `Camera`. This is why the camera is moving, but the sprite is not; the correct matrix is not being used.

Also the sprite is being rendered always at half the screen's width, and half the screen's height. To fix this Call [sprite.draw](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch%29). This will use the Sprite's internal position.

Set the `SpriteBatch` projection matrix via [batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#setProjectionMatrix%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4%29). This will cause the sprite to be rendered relative to the camera.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    translateCamera();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    renderer.setView(camera);

    renderer.render(bgLayers);

    //here's the line that was missing.
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();

    //be sure to call this instead of specifying position yourself!
    splayerSprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
    renderer.render(fgLayers);

}
```

You'll still need to handle snapping the camera's position to the sprite's position whenever WASD is pressed, but that's trivial.

```
//snap the camera to the sprite's center.
if(wasd_isDown){
    float centerX = sprite.getX()+sprite.getWidth()/2;
    float centerY = sprite.getY()+sprite.getHeight()/2;
    camera.position.set(x,y, 0);
}
```

If direction keys are pressed, just translate the camera's position vector via [Vector3.add](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.html#add%28float%29) like so:

```
if(!wasd_isDown){
    float deltaX = 0;
    float deltaY = 0;
    float MOVE_DIST = 10;//or whatever you need.

    if(leftPressed) deltaX = -MOVE_DIST;
    else if(rightPressed) deltaX = MOVE_DIST;

    if(upPressed)deltaY = MOVE_DIST;
    else if(downPressed)deltaY = -MOVE_DIST;

    camera.position.add(deltaX, deltaY, 0);
}
```

This will allow the camera to move independently only when the player uses directional keys, and will allow the sprite be be rendered in relation to the camera's orientation. It will also snap the camera immediately back to the sprite when WASD is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

`batch.draw(splayerSprite, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);`

You are telling the code to draw it to the center of your screen *every time*. You need to change `Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2` to actual values that change based on your input.

**Edit #2**: The line `batch.setProjectionmatrix(camera.combined);` is needed in addition to everything I have mentioned, I both did not notice that specific line was already in my code (it is included in the default libGDX project), and did not try running my demo with that line removed. I hope that clears up any confusion I may have caused.

**Edit**: Since apparently nobody really liked my answer, I went and wrote a demo using the controls specified in a clean libGDX game. Regardless of where the camera is aimed at (since it is being translated), the sprite was *always* being rendered in the center of the global screen. It is very much necessary to use the sprite's position in the `batch.draw()` instead of a static position, otherwise it will not move.

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture texture;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private Sprite background;

    private boolean lockToSprite;
    private Vector2 vecCamera;
    private Vector2 vecSprite;

    @Override
    public void create() {      
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        lockToSprite = true;
        vecCamera = new Vector2();
        vecSprite = new Vector2();

        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
        texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

        TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);

        sprite = new Sprite(region);
        sprite.setSize(0.1f * sprite.getWidth(), 0.1f * sprite.getHeight());
        sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
        sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2, -sprite.getHeight()/2);

        background = new Sprite(region);
        background.setOrigin(background.getWidth() / 2, background.getHeight() / 2);
        System.out.println(background.getOriginX());
        background.setPosition(-background.getWidth() / 2, -background.getHeight() / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        texture.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        camera.translate(vecCamera);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();

        camera.translate(vecCamera.cpy().mul(-1));

        float moveSensitivity = 0.9f;

        Vector2 vecInputSprite = new Vector2();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP))
            vecInputSprite.y += moveSensitivity;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN))
            vecInputSprite.y -= moveSensitivity;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT))
            vecInputSprite.x -= moveSensitivity;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT))
            vecInputSprite.x += moveSensitivity;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.N))
            vecSprite.set(new Vector2());

        Vector2 vecInputCamera = new Vector2();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W))
            vecInputCamera.y += moveSensitivity;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S))
            vecInputCamera.y -= moveSensitivity;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A))
            vecInputCamera.x -= moveSensitivity;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D))
            vecInputCamera.x += moveSensitivity;

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.R)) {
            vecCamera.set(new Vector2());
            lockToSprite = false;
        }

        if (vecInputCamera.len2() != 0)
            lockToSprite = false;
        else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.L))
            lockToSprite = true;

        if (lockToSprite) {
            vecCamera.set(vecSprite);
        } else {
            vecCamera.add(vecInputCamera);
        }

        vecSprite.add(vecInputSprite);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        background.draw(batch);
        sprite.setPosition(vecSprite.x, vecSprite.y);
        sprite.draw(batch);
        //batch.draw(sprite, vecSprite.x, vecSprite.y);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct that this is a problem, however if he's moving the camera and the sprite is stationary still, this won't fix his problem.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison When I said "change based on your input", it was strictly speaking about the sprite, considering the sprite is being drawn to the center of the global screen regardless of the camera's position, seeing as he already has `translateCamera()` called. Of course the camera position will also be affected by input however. I have a demo done in a fresh copy of a new libGDX game.

Comment: The sprite **will** move even if rendered at the same position each time because the camera's matrices will change. If this wasn't true, any statically positioned object would never appear to move across the screen when the camera was translated. The OP's problem is not updating the sprite batch's matrix to match the camera's matrix. +1 for the demo though. Show's effort and dedication!

Comment: @WilliamMorrison The sprite will render at a different position relative to the camera's altered position, but the OP asked for the sprite to move on the map. I would venture to guess that the OP rendered the map like they rendered the sprite, and thus the sprite would still not move relative to the map itself. As I said, the sprite was being drawn in the same place, which would be relative to the map not the camera. My demo includes the sprite's position as well, so it can move both relative to the camera *and* the map.

Comment: The sprite isn't relative to the camera or the map assuming the renderer uses the camera's matrix (`setView` makes me think it **does**.) The sprite isn't relative to anything. It's position is only a small part of this. You're missing the bigger issue, the camera's matrix not being used by the SpriteBatch.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Except for my mishap in my final sentence of my comment, I did not say the position of the sprite is relative to the camera, I said that the position it renders at will be different relative to the position at which the camera itself is pointing at. Also, I do not know how his renderer works, but `batch.draw(sprite, vecSprite.x, vecSprite.y);` is equivalent to `sprite.setPosition(vecSprite.x, vecSprite.y); sprite.draw(batch);`. His problem is that the sprite's rendering is locked to the camera, and the camera is not being locked to the player. I added locking to my answer.

Comment: You're confusing the issues, its unproductive. Lets start over. Sprite is rendered at center of screen, never moves. This is because of the batch matrix **doesn't match the camera's.** AND **the camera's position isn't being fixed to the sprite.** You only recently added this second part, you **never** noticed or didn't bother to explain the first. Just add an explanation for what you're doing to your question and let's wrap this up please?

Comment: The camera, when used correctly, will change what the viewport/screen is looking at. When the sprite is being rendered at the "center of the screen", its actually being rendered to the center of the scene because the SpriteBatch wasn't moved. If the camera was translated, it would appear to be elsewhere on the screen. If the sprite AND the camera were moved, the background/map would show up in a different location. I don't what what is contained in his `translateCamera()` method, but if the sprite is still being rendered in the middle, then the camera wasn't actually moved.

Comment: ...OR the `SpriteBatch` matrix wasn't set to the `Camera` matrix. Which it wasn't based on the code shown and the description given. As I've said many, many times now.

Comment: My answer might clear some things up for you if there's any confusion about what I'm saying? I only suggest this as there seems to be a disconnect between us I can't understand.

Comment: I think the disconnect was that by default, the projection matrix IS in the libGDX game, and I didn't notice that it was there. Everything I have been saying assumed that the projection matrix was being set (I say this now in hindsight), I hope this clears up the disconnect we had.